# Pairwise calculation of atom distances between two files with python

Tags: python

I have used bash so far to generate two files:

`File one` contains coordinates of C atoms of protein divided by space:

```
C2[0]  C2[1]  C2[2]

13.717 10.109 8.591
13.306 9.421 7.294
12.004 8.673 7.519
13.163 10.412 6.155
15.876 11.528 12.222
17.300 11.385 12.712
14.936 10.789 13.182
13.481 10.875 12.771
12.703 11.969 13.122
12.890 9.875 12.010
11.376 12.078 12.725
11.556 9.961 11.612
10.803 11.067 11.970
19.044 12.341 14.078
19.906 12.922 12.973
```

`File two` contains C atom coordinates of the ligand:

```
C1[0] C1[1]  C1[2]

0.510 -3.329 3.463
1.664 -2.694 4.189
1.864 -6.031 5.380
2.956 -6.810 4.984
4.038 -7.028 5.832
1.887 -5.446 6.650
2.974 -5.663 7.501
4.066 -6.436 7.093
5.204 -6.724 8.010
6.532 -6.775 7.600
7.539 -7.095 8.513
7.222 -7.396 9.831
5.894 -7.377 10.238
4.894 -7.058 9.331
```

How could I use foreach loop in python to calculate the distance of first line in `file two`, to each line in `file one` (this would generate 15 numbers as there are 15 lines in file one);

then second line of `file two`, to each line in `file one`.

To calculate the distance I need to use:

```
import math
def distance(c1, c2):
    x_dist = (c1[0] - c2[0])**2
    y_dist = (c1[1] - c2[1])**2
    z_dist = (c1[2] - c2[2])**2
    return math.sqrt(x_dist + y_dist + z_dist)
```

Now how to put the formula into foreach loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can access your file 1 and fil2 2 in matrix via `pands` and calculate the distance with `numpy`. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
file1='your_file1.txt'
file2='your_file2.txt'
f1=pd.read_csv(file1,sep='\t')
f2=pd.read_csv(file2,sep='\t')
f1=f1.apply(pd.to_numeric) #make sure f1 is numeric
f2=f2.apply(pd.to_numeric) #make sure f1 is numeric
f1=f1.T.values
f2=f2.T.values
print (f1.shape, f2.shape)
```

where `f1` and `f2` should be the matrices with 15 rows and 3 columns.

```
def distance(a,b):
    return np.sqrt(sum((a-b)**2))
DD=[distance(i,j) for i,j in zip(f1, f2)]
print (DD)
```

You can calculate the distance with the function `distance (a,b)`, which takes the two matrices as input. `DD` should return a list with 15 distances computed by the formula you showed.

Comment: I appreciate your help, so when I try it on my bigger file, I still get the error at the end that might be related to numpy: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "distance.py", line 13, in <module>
    DD=[distance(i,j) for i,j in zip(f1, f2)]
  File "distance.py", line 13, in <listcomp>
    DD=[distance(i,j) for i,j in zip(f1, f2)]
  File "distance.py", line 12, in distance
    return np.sqrt(sum((a-b)**2))
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (583,) (450,). .... When I read file 1 and file 2 they look fine though..

Comment: Could it be that the minus (-) before the number plays any role, cus I also get error message with some test files: TypeError: unsupported operand type for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: When you see "operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (583,) (450,)" if means your matrices have different shapes/length. You can `print (f1.shape,f2.shape)` to check that. Notice that the inputs to `distance` must have the same shape for matrice operation to make sense; otherwise you will have to truncate one of them.

Comment: Yes the datatype could be an issue, please see the edited answer!

Comment: With print I get (1, 583) (1, 450). I assume that should mean that I get 540 coordinates in file1 (lines) and 450 coordinates (lines) in file2? Since I am looking at calculating the distance of first three coordinates (first line) in file 2 and all three coordinates (all lines) in file 1 ; then after that second three coordinates (second line) in file 2 and all coordinates (lines) in file 1, that shouldn't be a problem right? It should be something like pairwise distance calculation between two files.

Comment: This is indeed off, I anticipate you will get (3,n) (3,n), where n is the number of lines you have. The plausible reason is, your file cannot be converted to a matrice with pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t'). Since I do not have your file, it is quite hard to suggest a solution.

Comment: Hm, because some of my lines start with - (minus), now with updated version I am getting error: ValueError: Unable to parse string "-15.597 -9.303 50.911". Other than this many traceback calls that involve different scripts in pandas module

Comment: Hm, I see. my file is literally what I posted here, but with file one is (3, 583) and file two is (3, 450). Outside of it, it is exactly the same thing as I posted here, only that some lines can start with negative number.

Comment: Actually, even when I try to run the script you posted here on the example above, I still get number or errors. Generally, I think if something would work on this example, would work on the bigger one as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216477/discussion-between-tianlinhe-and-sergio).